# move a file into a tag in svn

Tags: svn

I want to move a file into a tag in svn, what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
svn copy /path/to/file/file.toadd /path/to/tag
```

Remember SVN doesn't really have a tag concept, so tags / branches can be modified

Answer (score 4):

The best way is not to do it. Tags are supposed to represent  a snapshot at  a particular point in time, so adding to them later doesn't make much sense.  Tags cost almost nothing to make, so why not simply create  a new tag with the added file?

Answer (score 1):

It's not really nice to mess up a tag like that, but it's possible using svn commands with the full URL

```
svn cp \
  http://path/to/repository/trunk/path/to/your/file \
  http://path/to/repostory/tags/your-tag/path/to/your/file
```

You can use svn mv, svn rm etc. to get the desired effect.

Comment: I had to remove it first on the tag side, then I was able to copy it

Answer (score 0):

By "move", do you actually mean that you don't want it to continue existing where it is now? If so, and if you use the standard [recommended layout](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.importing.html#svn.tour.importing.layout) for Subversion repositories, then an `svn mv trunk/whateverfile tags/whateverfile` would probably do it.

Otherwise, it's probably best to create a new tag that represents the current state of trunk.